# Time incorrect after add format date in gson builder

Tags: android, gson, date-formatting

I have json string which is returned from `mongodb`.

```
[{"_id":"578bb51aa51d15940688809e","name":"aaa","date":"2016-07-20T11:47:39.302Z"}]
```

I used `gson` to convert the Java Object. I got `Unparseable date: "2016-07-20T11:47:39.302Z"`. So I added date format to `gson` builder.

```
Gson gson=  new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'").create();
```

The date result is `Wed Jul 20 11:47:39 MMT 2016`. The time is `incorrect`.

What is the better date format pattern for date string?

How can I choose the suitable date format pattern by the given date string?

Comment: What is incorrect about the time? The time is `11:47:39` in both strings.

Comment: Actually the date is creation date. It should be `16:48` cos I added this document at that time.

Comment: @user1156041 So you get unparsable date problem or incorrect time? Why it's incorect, if it's the same time in json from mongo in your `result`? Please be more clear.

Comment: I'm confused about what you are trying to accomplish. It seems like you want to deserialize the MongoDB string into a Java object. If the date in the original string and the resulting date are equal, I do not see the issue.

Comment: yes. I would like to know the correct date format pattern. I don't think I have correct one.

Comment: @Bryan I run this javascript `new Date().toJSON();` now, I got this
`2016-07-20T13:49:45.589Z` But I don't think u can say the time is `13:49`. Cos it is `20:20` in here.

Comment: I'm not really following the times in your comments, here, but I would suggest that you take note of the time zones in your question. The time in the JSON is in UTC, but your result is in MMT. It looks like GSON is just applying your local time zone without correctly adjusting the time. Is this what you're seeing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you are having an issue with timezone information. Both the JavaScript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object and the Java [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object represent a point in [*universal coordinated time*](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (UTC). Neither the JavaScript `Date` object nor the Java `Date` object contain timezone information.

---

**Side note:** The Java `Date` object *does* actually contain timezone information, which is why you see the timezone (`MMT` in your case) when you call `date.toString()`. Though, this timezone should be ***ignored***, as the timezone irregularities highlight some of the [many issues](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) with the Java 7- date/time classes.

---

The [`GsonBuilder().setDateFormat()`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#setDateFormat-java.lang.String-) method sets the string format that a Java `Date` object should be serialized to and deserialized from. This format does not contain any timezone information either because the `Date` object does not contain that information.

In order to *display* the UTC time your `Date` object represents in the correct timezone, you must provide that timezone. This is not done during deserialization with `Gson`, but when you actually display the date/time:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

String zonedDateTime = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
```

---

Android also comes with a handy [`DateUtils`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html) class to use instead of `SimpleDateFormat` that will handle the timezone information for you, as well as `Locale` information.

```
DateUtils.formatDateTime(getContext(), date.getTime(),
                        DateUtils.FORMAT_NUMERIC_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL);
```

Comment: Yes, perfectly work if I change `simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));`